# How to add integers and strings in the same vector?

Tags: c++, run-length-encoding

I need help for my university homework. i'm still new to this.

Basically i am doing a run-length encoding and i don't know how to add the letter after the counter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void error(std::string str)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(str);
}

int main()
{       int counter = 1;
        std::string id;
        std::vector<int> v;
        std::cout << "Enter the data to be compressed: ";
        std::cin >> id;

        try
        {   for(int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++)
            {
                if(std::isdigit(id[i]))
                   error("invalid input");
            }

            std::cout << "The compressed data is: ";
            for(int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++)
            {
                if(id[i] == id[i+1])
               {
                   counter++;
               }
               else if(id[i]!= id[i+1])
               {
                   v.push_back(counter);
                   v.push_back(id[i]);
                   counter=1;
               }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++)
                std::cout << v[j];
        }
        catch(std::runtime_error& str)
        {
            std::cerr << "error: " << str.what() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

 return 0;
}
```

For example if i input aaabbb, the probram should output 3a3b. The problem is that it outputs 397398 97 and 98 being the ascii code for a and b.
i don't know how to put the letter after the counter and for them to be in the same vector.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `class` to encapsulate the *two* pieces of information that make up a chunk of encoded data (a quantity and a letter).

Comment: The thing is that we still didn't learn classes properly and i don't know how to do it very well

Comment: Sounds like it is a parallel "array" problem then

Comment: Then use `std::pair<T1, T2>`, no one will tell you about it anyway)

Comment: If you have already learnt std::map this is a perfect case for using it, otherwise how about 2 vectors: 1 std::vector<char>  1 std::vector<int> ?

Comment: Why not just output the required data instead of storing it in `v`?  `std::cout << counter << id[i]`

Comment: i would've outputted that separately but the problem requires us to store the compressed data in one vector

Comment: Store everything as a `std::string` then?

Comment: i get the error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'int' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: @czarczar You have to convert the `int` to ` strign` using `to_string`.

Comment: So what if your input string had been "aaab"? Would you expect: "3a1b" or "3ab"?

Comment: yea "3a1b" that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize as a string try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

void error(std::string str) {
throw std::runtime_error(str);
}

int main() {


std::ostringstream stream;
int counter = 1;
std::string id;

std::cout << "Enter the data to be compressed: ";
std::cin >> id;

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) {
        if (std::isdigit(id[i]))
            error("invalid input");
    }

    std::cout << "The compressed data is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) {
        if (id[i] == id[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
        } else if (id[i] != id[i + 1]) {
            stream << counter;
            stream << (char) id[i];

            counter = 1;
        }
    }


    std::cout <<  stream.str() << std::endl;

} catch (std::runtime_error& str) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << str.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`v[j]` from `std::cout << v[j]` is of type `int` and that is why `std::cout` writes a number. To write it as a character, you should cast `v[j]` to `char` as follows: `std::cout << (char)v[j]`. In this way, `std::cout` will use the `char` specialization, not the `int` one.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers might give you the output you need, I believe the idiomatic way to solve this is using a class to hold both the character and its count. There are two obvious choices.

## std::pair

Could also be `std::tuple` if you prefer it for consistency or whatever reason. Save your results in a `std::vector<std::pair<char, int>`. This saves the information, but to print it you would need to define an appropriate function. Add elements via

```
v.emplace_back(character, count);
```

## Wrapper Class

If you want to offer some functionality without outside helper classes, define a custom wrapper class such as the following.

```
class CharacterCount {
private:
    char character;
    int count;

public:
    CharacterCount(char character, int count):
        character(character), count(count) {}

    explicit operator std::string() const { return std::to_string(count) + character;

    // Other helper functions or constructors you require
}
```

This simplifies printing

```
for (auto& character_count : v)
    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(character_count);
```

I believe because `std::ostream::operator<<` is templated, you cannot get an implicit conversion to `std::string` to work. I would advise against implicit conversion anyway.

You can use the same `emplace_back` syntax as before because we offer an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So you take your input in a `string` and ultimately just need to stream this information out, ultimately meaning there's really no reason to store the information in a `vector`, just output it! You can use [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a lambda to find the non-consecutive character (or [`find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) if you prefer.)

```
for(string::const_iterator finish, start = cbegin(id); start != cend(id); start = finish) {
    finish = find_if(start, cend(id), [value = *start](const auto i) { return i != value; } );

    cout << distance(start, finish) << *start;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/OQO4kw)